# Import xlrd numbers as str

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm trying to import data from an .xlsx file with xlrd module in python, a few cells have data as numbers, and some others numbers with letters for example 222930X, by default python import this numbers as floats, I'd tried converting this numbers as ints but this would show an error in cases where the cell has numbers and letters.

My question is, how can I convert this data in str?

Thank you very much in advance...

My .py

```
import xlrd

brief = raw_input('Brief: ')
page = input('Pagina: ')
book = xlrd.open_workbook(brief)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(page)
date = str(datetime.date.today())
rename = date+categorianame+'.html'

sku1 = int(sheet.cell_value(4, 1))
sku1_str = str(sku1)
sku1_a = sku1_str
sku1_b = []
for x in sku1_a:
    sku1_b.append(str(x))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert a float into a str just use this code
`my_string = str(my_var)`

You could try something like that :

```
if isinstance(x, float):
   x = int(x)
sku1_b.append(str(x))
```

That should get rid of the '.0' you get when converting the float into a string only when needed (when x is a actually a float).

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work, if I use str() it brings the result as a string of the float '3725668.0' when it should bring only de characters in the cell and the cell doesn't have the --> .0